# how to forced stop timer widget while i want to direct to the new page

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to directing to the next page while my timer widget is running, when i use this, always had an error : **This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context** i know the error because the timer widget still running, but if i put `timer.cancel` inside
`if (_startTimeVerification  = 25){}`, it's still error

```
Timer? _time;
int _startTimeVerification = 120;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTimer();
  }

  void directPage(){
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'next_page');
  }

  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);

    _time = Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) {
        if (_startTimeVerification == 0) {
          setState(() {
            timer.cancel();
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _startTimeVerification--;
              if (_startTimeVerification  = 25){
                directPage();
              }
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _time.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

cannot direct page, because the error :
Exception has occurred.
Error: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.
dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:3  throw*
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 951:9                            
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 956:14                           get context
packages/we_healthy/screen/user_auth/pending_auth.dart 49:13                 
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 80:9

and can directing to the new page without an error

Comment: What's this line packages/we_healthy/screen/user_auth/pending_auth.dart 49:13?